# How i can copy term sets from on farm to another and preserve the term sets GUIDs

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, import, term-set

I have 2 sharepoint farm 2013 for 2 different customers. now i want to export a wiki page list from one farm and then import it to another farm. now the wiki page list is inside an enterprise wiki site collection, and have 5 custom site columns of type Managed Metadata which are linked to term sets. now i export the wiki page from source farm using this powershell:-

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://servername/kb/*****/" -ItemUrl "Pages" -Path "c:\wikipage.cmp" -CompressionSize 1000 -IncludeVersions All  -Force –Verbose
```

then on the destination farm i imported the list.  now the wiki pages were imported correctly (content, page layout, etc...), but i have noted that the wiki page list's managed metadata columns were not linked to the correct term sets on the destination farm. after some investigation, seems the managed metadata columns on the destination farm will try to find a term set inside the destination farm which have the same GUID as the source farm. so my question is how i can copy the related term sets from the source farm to the destination farm and preserve the term sets' GUIDs ..is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify GUIDs for items. The only way to do what you want to do is to backup the MMS database and restore it to the target farm.

Comment: i do not want to specify/update the GUIDs for the terms inside the destination farm.. now i am asking if i can move the whole term sets with their underlying terms from source farm to destination farm, and preserve their GUIDs.. so when i import the wiki pages library, the wiki page columns and the wiki pages themselves will be automatically linked to the correct term sets and terms...

Comment: Again, backup and restoring the MMS database is your only option. And when I say "specify", it means you can't explicitly provide a value regardless of how you're doing it.

Comment: so you mean i will need to backup/restore the MMS which stores the term-sets? and does this MMS only contain the term sets or it contains other info ?

Comment: It contains everything you see when you manage the Term Store.

Comment: @Trvor so since on the destination farm i already have a managed metadata service configured so it already have its own MMS.. so in this case i will need to create another managed metadata service and then restore the MMS db from the source farm... is this correct ?

Comment: That would be correct.